# C# Read binary file as string then save as binary file

Tags: encoding

I've been given string data (stored in a database) where the originator read binary tiff files as a string using something like (they actually used the VB FileSystemObject):

`var txt = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\some_image.tiff");`

I need to re-create the original tiff files. I've tried looping through all encodings with:

```
var txt = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\test\some_image.tiff");
var encodings = Encoding.GetEncodings();
for (var i = 0; i < encodings.Length; i++)
{
   File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\test\some_image_" + i + ".tiff", encodings[i].GetEncoding().GetBytes(txt));
}
```

but to no avail.

Comment: They almost certainly lost data, basically - you shouldn't even try getting it back. Treating arbitrary binary data as text - other than in the *very* special case of using ISO-8859-1 - basically loses information. Anything that isn't valid a UTF-8 byte sequence (in this case, as that's how you're reading the file) will end up with "not the original bytes" when you write it out again.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I concluded as well but wasn't 100% sure that is the case. Are you aware of any documentation source that states that is the case? (would help with a rebuttal)

Comment: No, it's not the sort of thing that would be documented any more than "if you print out source code and shred it, you're probably not going to have a good time reconstructing it". If we had the *exact* code used (with all the context such as default character encodings) we could probably demonstrate the problem by creating two *different* files (just a few bytes should do) that end up being stored in the database as the same data. That should be enough evidence that information is being lost.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  Yes, I hit them back with "I suspect there's data loss. Show me you can read the image then I'll continue investigating the issue". :-)